# Angular directive templateUrl trying to GET from Express

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-directive

I'm trying to get a third-party Angular directive ([ngCart](http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs)) to work with my Angular application. It seems like the `ngcart` directives are looking for a templateUrl as a relative path to the directive, and instead it seems like Express is trying to serve up the files instead of the directive finding the HTML file at the relative `templateUrl` path.

#### Project structure

```
projectName
    | - bower_components/
    | - node_modules/
    | - public/
        | - css
        | - index.html
        | - app.js (angular app)
    | - src/
        | - server.js (express app)
        | - routes/
        | - models/
    | - package.json
```

#### server.js

```
...
app.use("/", express.static("public"));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/../bower_components'));

app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log("App is listening");
});
```

#### third-party directive file causing issues:

```
templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
    if (typeof attrs.templateUrl == 'undefined') {
        return 'template/ngCart/addtocart.html';  // This is the relative path that's freaking out
    } else {
        return attrs.templateUrl;
    }
}
```

The console error I'm getting is:
`GET http://localhost:8000/template/ngCart/addtocart.html 404 (Not Found)`

It seems like express is trying to serve up the HTML file in the `template` folder inside the third-party directive, but I just want it to be a relative path to the HTML file without express being involved.

Comment: express will *always* be involved, and the path is relative to the `index.html`, not the path of the directive.

Comment: @Claies Then why does the code in the third-party directive give a relative `templateUrl` path? That's not something I wrote, and unless they _really_ messed up, it seems like I shouldn't be changing their directive's `templateUrl`. (That would lead to me changing dozens of lines of their code.) Perhaps I'm not understanding something...

Comment: https://github.com/snapjay/ngCart/issues/6.  It seems your concern was discussed with the developer of that directive in the past, and not changed or documented more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Claies in the comments, someone brought this concern up with the creator of ngCart ([thread found here](https://github.com/snapjay/ngCart/issues/6)), to which he responded saying that you basically are supposed to copy the template files into a folder called "template" in your main public directory. It isn't documented anywhere in the [ngCart documentation](http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs) though, so hopefully this can help someone in the future.

It appears this is the most common way to bring in third-party angular directives that have their own template files.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

I'm no expert in AngularJS, I've been fighting this exact issue with a programming buddy all afternoon.

Eventually we tripped across [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690105/template-not-found-using-angularjs-ngcart-to-build-shopping-cart-for-ecommerce) which describes a vastly more elegant solution.

(I've also commented on the GitHub issue tracking page, for future reference.)

In short:

```
<ngcart-summary template-url="/libraries/ngCart/template/ngCart/summary.html"></ngcart-summary>
```