# Template not found- using angularjs ngCart to build shopping cart for ecommerce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, shopping-cart, ng-template

I am building an angular web app and am trying to incorporate ngCart.  I installed it using `bower install ngcart --save`, incorporated the bower file in my index.html file and injected it as a dependency into the app.  When I try to use the `<ngcart-addtocart>` directive (only incorporating the `ngcart-addtocart` tag in the view file) I get the following error - `Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/ngCart/addtocart.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)`

I suspect it is something simple I am missing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look in the `ngCart` directory that `bower` installed downloaded the files to.

```
app/public/libraries/ngCart/template/
└── ngCart
    ├── addtocart.html
    ├── cart.html
    ├── checkout.html
    └── summary.html
```

then in the directive write in the template location.

```
<ngcart-summary template-url="/libraries/ngCart/template/ngCart/summary.html"></ngcart-summary>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ngcart folder there is a template folder name,
you copy it to the project folder, because it contains the html he complained lack.